# Return an array of exp values with an ease parameter

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

I need a method to get an interval of integer distributed between a range of two integers (min, max) with an ease value (-100;100) to define the "acceleration" of this values from the left to the right.

## How to use

```
foo(min, max, samples, ease);
```

- **min** is the start int (included)
- **max** is the end int (included)
- **samples** the number of values to returned
- **ease** the ease from -100 to 100

In return I need an array of integer.

## What it's expected

```
foo(5, 20, 4, 0); // [5, 10, 15, 20]
foo(5, 20, 4, 1.3); // [5, 7, 12, 20]
foo(5, 20, 4, 100); // [5, 16, 18, 20]
foo(5, 20, 4, -100); // [5, 7, 9, 20]
```

From the top to the bottom (with fanciful returned values for the last three result) :

- 4 values from 5 to 20 with a linear progression.
- 4 values from 5 to 20 with a small progression.
- 4 values with a quick progression.
- 4 values with a very slow progression.

## What I tried

I tried to create a javascript method with a sin curve but the return doesn't contain the start and last values and my ease value is probably (certainly, mandatory) incorrect :

```
function foo(min, max, samples, ease) {
  const ret = [];
  for (var i = min/max; i < 1; i += 1/samples) {
    ret.push(Math.round((1 - Math.sin((1 - i) * Math.PI / ease)) * max)); 
  }
  return ret;
}
```

What is the best way to create a method like this?

Comment: I don't understand this concept of ease. Can you explain it another way?

Comment: Also, I'm _definitely_ not a JS person, but can you really mutate a `const` array?

Comment: 1,5 with ease 0 you get 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. A linear progression.

Comment: OK, so there's almost certainly no way to explicitly program different progressions like this in a closed form.

Comment: @erip Yes, the elements of an array can be changed where the array is defined using `const`

Comment: 1.5 with ease 100 it's like a easeOutExpo and -100 it's like a easeInExpo.

Comment: Why do you expect the values described at Question at _"What it's expected"_?

Comment: I not expect this values (except the first example) I want a correct algo to return values with a ease progression like my example.

Comment: Then why did you include an array adjacent to each call, indicating that array to be the expected result of the function call with those specific parameters passed?

Comment: I'm sorry. I dont undertand what do you mean. It's just four example with the result expected on the right (with fanciful values for the last three call)

Comment: Why are values on the right expected? There are no "fanciful values" in math.

Comment: Yes but I am not a math professional, the linear progression is simple to found with 4 values. With the others values I need this method to find the correct values so it's just fancy result to demonstrate what I need like result.

Comment: Then how will you know if or when a solution to your inquiry is correct?

Comment: One important variable missing from your concept is the element of time. See http://upshots.org/actionscript/jsas-understanding-easing, https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/

Comment: I repeat again the "what it's expected" is for the call and how the parameters (in prorioty the ease value) change the progression from the start to the end value.

Comment: Again, there is no "fancy" in math. There is the concept of "imaginary numbers" within the study of complex numbers and geometry, though not "fancy" or "fanciful" numbers

Comment: I dont think the time is a needed paramter. It's the case with actioscript where this method is used to display an animation. In my case the time is replaced with the array index.

Comment: Your inquiry is not at all clear. Unless the expectation is for a viewer to write the code for you, to attain the "fanciful" result. Consider omitting the terms "fancy" or "fanciful" when the subject matter is mathematics. Have you read the links at previous comment?

Comment: Yes : "current time (or position) of the tween. This can be seconds or frames, steps, seconds, ms, whatever", so in my case the Time can an index (like the iterator). I cant write the correct return of the last three result because I dont now how to calculate it.

Comment: Would suggest that you take the time to review the links posted at previous comment; the content should be of help towards solving your own inquiry. If you are not familiar with how to formulate mathematical procedures, the  first step would be to begin with a basic process, then proceed. Instead of including inaccurate expected results at a Question and then asking for the correct result.

Comment: Simply begin by stating that you do not know how to derive the correct result, and thus, the expected result is unknown to you. Though you may know the common or lay name of the curve on the graph you are trying to create. Again, the links at previous comment directly address the subject matter of your inquiry, in relative depth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a sinewave, use exponential curves. Using powers of 3 you even get approximately the results you described (at the endpoints `[-100, 100]`)

```js
//simple linear interpolation
var interpolate = (a,b,t) => a*(1-t) + b*t;

function foo(min, max, samples, ease=0){
 var pow = interpolate(1, ease<0? 3: 1/3, Math.abs(+ease || 0)/100);
 var arr = Array(+samples);
 for(var i=0; i<arr.length; ++i)
  arr[i] = interpolate(min, max, Math.pow(i / (samples-1), pow));
 return arr;
}

function round(v){ return Math.round(v * 1E5)/1E5 }
foo(-100, 100, 11).forEach(ease => console.log("ease: %s values: [ %s ]", ease, foo(5, 20, 4, ease).map(round).join(", ")))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

Comment: _"I am not a math professional"_ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44401738/return-an-array-of-exp-values-with-an-ease-parameter#comment75803579_44401738.  For disambiguation perhaps consider noting that `E` is not representative of the number _`e`_

Comment: @guest271314 wich `E`? I'm not using Euler's number nor logarithms in any way, in this code.

Comment: `Math.round(v * 1E5)/1E5` Yes, the `E` used by JavaScript is not the mathematical irrational constant _`e`_,  the base of natural logarithms; commonly referred to as "Euler's number"

Comment: _"The use of E-notation facilitates data entry and readability in textual communication since it minimizes keystrokes, avoids reduced font sizes and provides a simpler and more concise display, but it is not encouraged in publications."_ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E-notation

Comment: @Thomas perfect ! Thanks

Comment: @guest271314, you definitively complex the question. I need a method to get a red value. A red ? It's not a color in physics, what is the wavelength you want ?

Comment: @Jerome Well, all colors are wavelengths. If remember accurately, "red" would be between 600 and 700 nanometer wavelength.